# Delete folder and contents older than 2 days PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a folder structure in xampp

```
Deletefiles
     --Uploads
       --Test1
       --Test2
     --index.php
```

index.php i write script to delete all folder and its contents in uploads such as test1 and test2

```
$foldername = array('test1','test2');
function recursiveRemove($dir) {
    $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
    if (is_array($structure)) {
        foreach($structure as $file) {

            if (is_dir($file)) recursiveRemove($file);
            elseif (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}

foreach($foldername as $fname){
     recursiveRemove("uploads/".$fname."/");
}
```

Its working fine.But i want to delete only folder which are older than 2 days.How can change my script.

Comment: By checking file dates

Comment: That i know dagon.but how can we call that recursiveremove function for files only older than 2 days.

Comment: Look at filemtime() and unlink files if older than.... http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dagon pointed out you need to verify the date of the file object before deleting.

Add this to your `foreach`. The condition will ask if the date of the file object is smaller than the current time minus 60 seconds * 60 (minutes) * 24 (hours) * 2 (days).

```
foreach($structure as $file) {
    if (filemtime($file) < time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 2) ) {
        if (is_dir($file)) recursiveRemove($file);
        elseif (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Note that your recursive function will not delete files that do not match the condition ( they are newer than 2 days) inside directories that do match the condition (older than 2 days).
Making `rmdir` throw a warning if it's not empty.

Comment: Okey..then where t put rmdir($dir)

Comment: Its only delete the files ryt...Then how can i call rmdir for deleted files

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
function recursiveRemove($dir) {
 $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
 if (is_array($structure)) {
    foreach($structure as $file) {

        if (is_dir($file)) {
           recursiveRemove($file);
        } elseif (is_file($file)) {
          $lastmod = filemtime($file);
          //48 hours in a day * 3600 seconds per hour
          if((time() - $lastmod) > 48*3600) {
            unlink($file);
           }
        } 
   }
 }
 $dirlastmod = filemtime($dir);   
 if((time() - $dirlastmod) > 48*3600) {
      rmdir($dir);
  }
}

foreach($foldername as $fname){
 recursiveRemove("uploads/".$fname."/");
}
```

Comment: its only deleting files not folder i edited like **$foldername = array('test1','test2');
function recursiveRemove($dir) {
    $structure = glob(rtrim($dir, "/").'/*');
 $cond = 0;
    if (is_array($structure)) {
        foreach($structure as $file) {
            
   if (filemtime($file) < time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 2) ) {
    $cond = 1;
    if (is_dir($file)) recursiveRemove($file);
    elseif (is_file($file)) unlink($file);
    
   }
        }
    }
    if($cond == 1){
 rmdir($dir); 
 }
}

foreach($foldername as $fname){
     
  recursiveRemove("uploads/".$fname."/");
 }**